# How to convert id as order number in ng-options group by..?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

This is my code

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6cf3h54x/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <input type="text" ng-model = "data.name" ><br>
   <input type="text" ng-model = "data.value" ><br>
   <input type="text" ng-model = "data.id" ><br>
   <input type="button" value="ADD" ng-click = "addIntoArr(data.name, 
       data.value, data.id)" ng-disabled= !data.name>
   <select ng-model="selectItem"  ng-options="currOption as 'order' + 
     (data.indexOf(currOption)+1) group by currOption.name for currOption
         in data"></select>
   Data : {{selectItem.name}} 
</div>
```

**Here is my Js code**

```
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
       name: "AM",
       value: "11",
       id: "2"
    }, {
       name: "PM",
       value: "12",
       id: "3"
    }, {
      name: "PM",
      value: "12",
      id: "23"
    }, {
      name: "PM",
      value: "12",
      id: "33"
    }, {
      name: "AMT",
      value: "13",
      id: "33"
    }, {
      name: "WAT",
      value: "14",
      id: "21"
   }];

  $scope.addIntoArr = function (name, value, id) {
     $scope.data.push({
        name: name,
        value: value,
        id: id
    });
  }
   $scope.selectItem = $scope.data[0];
}
```

Here is my array I was using label **AM, PM, AWT, WAT**. and each has a order ([Please check fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6cf3h54x/3/)). I want each label order show with number like order1 in **AM**, order1, order2, order3 in **PM** and so on. and if I add new entry in array then recently added entry should be shown in drop down with order number and Related label shown in **Data**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you include some external library like [lodash](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lodash.js/) and format your data into more convenient structure. Then, instead of banging your head against the wall with `ng-options`, you could use `ng-repeat`.

Consider the following:

```
// group existing data by object's name using lodash _.groupBy
$scope.groupedData = _.groupBy($scope.data, 'name');
```

This gives your following data structure for `groupedData`, so there's `key` and `value` where key is e.g. `AM` and value is array of objects all having same `name`.

[image: imgur]

Then you could have following template for your `select`.

```
<select ng-model="selectItem">
  <optgroup ng-repeat="(key, items) in groupedData" label="{{ key }}">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" 
            value="{{ item }}" 
            ng-bind="'order' + (items.indexOf(item) + 1)"></option>
  </optgroup>    
</select>
```

Which gives you what you are after, no?

[image: imgur]

Comment: hey #MikkoViitala thanks for response. I was try this but there is nothing shown in drop down. Could you please check this [This FIddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6cf3h54x/5/). Where i was added loadsh and put ur code inside this please check where i was wrong. Thanks

Comment: oops..:) .  wow it's working. Please tell me one more thing. If add new entry with existing Key then how they will be show in drop down.

Comment: I don't know, test in your fiddle. If you add to groupedData then values will be replaced, if you add to data, then group again.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `$index` inside `ng-options`. However you can get the current index by using `indexOf` on the data item passing the current option.

```
<select 
   ng-model="selectItem" 
   ng-options="currOption as 'order' + (data.indexOf(currOption)+1) group by currOption.name for currOption in data"></select>
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/6cf3h54x/3/

Comment: oh great thanks. and how to show selected label in Data. and it is possible to onload page show some value  selected in drop down ??

Comment: @Abhishek - You have to set the `$scope.selectItem` to whichever item you want to set from `$scope.data`. E.g `$scope.selectItem = $scope.data[0]`. There is slight change in the html which I have corrected it. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/6cf3h54x/2/

Comment: But onload on page(first apperance) drop down not selected any value and change value through dropdown it's reflact nothing in Data:  Please check this in fiddle.

Comment: Dropdown is selected on page load itself. There was a typo I just fixed it. Try again http://jsfiddle.net/6cf3h54x/3/

Comment: yes, this is working. thank you so much @ShankarSangoli. 
One more this if i added new entry in array then how it is shown selected in drop down.

Comment: You can updata the data object angular will take care of updating the select html. To change the selected item you just have to set the appropriate item in `$scope.seletItem` like I showed earlier.

Comment: this is quiet good. But my requirement is to show order number according to label as mentioned in Question description. I want each label order show with number like order1 in AM, order1, order2, order3 in PM and so on. but currently showing only index. If i add In label PM  anew entry then it show order 7 , isteand it shown order number 4 .

Comment: Which means each label show like that in AM order1, in PM  order1, order2, order3 and so on. If i add new entry in exist label name then it should we show inside label . suppose i added new entry with label name AM and then this result not shown  into the last it shown with existing label and order number will be increase. like AM order1 new entry will be order2. CURRENTLY we are added new index in AM label and out put is ORDER7. Please give me a help.

Comment: I am not able to understand you.

Comment: ok, I was elaborate you what i want actually. In my drop down i was using label like AM, PM, AWT and so on. each label has orders like order1, order2, order3 ok. currently as shown in [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6cf3h54x/3/). Here we are show order number according **Index** like in **AM**  order1, in   **PM** order2, order3, order4, in **AWT** ordere5, and in **WAT** order6. ** BUT**  i want to show like this in AM order1, in PM order1, order2, order3, IN AWT order1, in WAT order1. **Means** each label have different indexing.

Comment: And if i added new entry with existing LABEL then it will we added this under the existing label and order number increase + 1 with existing order number in Label. For Example i added new entry in **PM** then it will we added in **PM** label as order4. Currently in [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/6cf3h54x/3/) if i added new entry in **PM** then it was added in **PM** label but order7. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$index` with `ng-options`. Make use of `indexOf` instead. You can do something like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectItem" ng-options="currOption.id as 'order'+data.indexOf(currOption) group by currOption.name for currOption in data"></select>
```

Comment: Great & thanks. and one more thing how to show selected label in Data. and it is possible to onload page show some value selected in drop down ??

Comment: @Abhishek Your `selectedItem` shud be `$scope.selectItem = $scope.data[0].id;`

Comment: it is working in console.log but in fiddle its not working. Can you check this and onload drop down not selected also. Please check this in fiddle.

Comment: @Abhishek For AM/PM to work, you need to remove `.id` part. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02bfsd1j/4/)

Comment: i check this error. Thank you for asking.
 One more this if i added new entry in array then how it is shown selected in drop down.

Comment: @Abhishek If you are selecting like `$scope.selectItem = $scope.data[$scope.data.length-1];` then always the last item will be selected.

Comment: this is quiet good. But my requirement is to show order number according to label as mentioned in Question description. I want each label order show with number like order1 in AM, order1, order2, order3 in PM and so on. but currently showing only index. If i add In label PM anew entry then it show order 7 , isteand it shown order number 4

Comment: Which means each label show like that in AM order1, in PM  order1, order2, order3 and so on. If i add new entry in exist label name then it should we show inside label . suppose i added new entry with label name AM and then this result not shown  into the last it shown with existing label and order number will be increase. like AM order1 new entry will be order2. CURRENTLY we are added new index in AM label and out put is ORDER7. Please give me a help.